# How to turn off remembering the position in file for SMPlayer?

Tags: smplayer

When opening the file SMPlayer restores the position at which the file was closed.

How to turn that off so that it always opens the file at the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch SMPlayer and open *Options* > *Preferences* (or simply press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>). In *General* section, under *Media settings* **uncheck** the "*Remember time position*" option.

[image]